# New class object error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, nullreferenceexception, blazor

I encountered this error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

When creating the countStats object, it is NULL, after which I try to assign a value to the field of this class and get this error.
What am I doing wrong?

```
public async Task<MainPageViewModel> GetMainPageViewModelAsync()
        {
            var model = new MainPageViewModel();
            var countStats = new StatsCountsViewModel(); // NULL

            if (!_cache.TryGetValue("CountsStats", out countStats))
            {
                var result = await _contextRepository.GetStatsMainPageAsync();

                countStats.CountSms = "300"; //ERROR
                countStats.CountUsers = "600";
                countStats.CountSuccessForecast = "1228";

                model.Stats = countStats;

                _cache.Set("CountsStats", countStats, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
                {
                    AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
                });
            }

            var forecasts = await _contextRepository.GetForecastsOnSaleAsync();

            foreach (var item in forecasts)
            {
                model.Forecasts.Add(item);
                model.Bookmaker.Add(await _contextRepository.GetBookmakersForForecastsAsync(item.Id));
            }

            return model;

        }
```

```
 public class StatsCountsViewModel
    {
        public string CountUsers { get; set; }
        public string CountSms { get; set; }
        public string CountSuccessForecast { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: While good answer by John provides copy-paste ready solution there is really nothing new in your question - code explicitly runs when you get no object from cache and such case (variable initialized with default `null` value) already covered in standard duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
_cache.TryGetValue("CountsStats", out countStats)
```

`out` will change the object that `countStats` is pointing to. If it's found in the cache, then it will be the cached object. Great! If it isn't, then it will be `null`. You need to create a new instance in this case.

You should change your code to this:

```
var countStats = null;

if (!_cache.TryGetValue("CountsStats", out countStats))
{
    countStats = new StatsCountsViewModel();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if (!_cache.TryGetValue("CountsStats", out countStats))
```

You are passing the `countStats` using the `out` word, and somewhere in the try get value,  you are setting a null in there.